# load values of getRowData to another grid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm planning to get data from grid1 using getRowData & populate another grid(ViewGrd-in my case) with those data. I'm doing following. I think I'm very close to it but missing some format or may be don't know how to extract from "data"- array in my case. Please take a look at following code. I need to do something at the very end inside for loop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    var rows= buybackgrid.jqGrid('getRowData');
    for (var i=0, il=ids.length; i < il; i++) {
        if(buybackgrid.find('#'+ids[i]).hasClass('ui-state-highlight')){
            var row = rows[i];
            data.push($.param(row));
        } 
    }
    ViewGridInit(data);
});

function ViewGridInit(data){
    jQuery("#ViewGrd").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        height:'100%',
        width:'100%',
        colNames: result.colNamesData, //Don't worry abt this
        colModel: result.colModelData,//Don't worry abt this
        rowNum : 100,
        shrinkToFit :false,
        altRows: true,
        altclass:'altRow',
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true,
        gridComplete:function (){
        },
        serializeGridData: function (data){ 
            return $.toJSON(data);   
        }
    });

    //end of jQuery("#ViewGrd").jqGrid({
    //Question : I need to take the record from "data" parameter & load
    //"#ViewGrd" locally with that. Following didn't work for me.

   //"data" looks like this :
     lead_date=01%2F12%2F2014&asset_name=Hosted+VoIP+vs+VoIP+PBX%3A+And+the+winner+is.&company_name=Cisco&cost=28.00&lead_event_id=827327&Company_Size=5%2C000%2B&Job_Title=Senior+Management+(SVP%2FGM%2FDirector)&Industry=Telecommunications&Country=United+States


    for(var i=0;i<totalselectedLeads;i++){
        jQuery("#ViewGrd").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,data[i]); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

-A

Comment: Hi Oleg I was hoping for an answer from you.Any idea?

Comment: @user659469: Just now I read accidentally your comment. Probably the question is already solved. Next time if you want to send me a message you should write comment somewhere where I wrote either an answer or an comment. You should use @Oleg (see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) for details).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try some thing like

```
 var data= $(gridId).jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

The above statement returns you the whole data present in the grid as JSON.

Then you can use some thing like this to populate the grid.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        jQuery("#ViewGrd").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,data[i]); 
    }
```

Hope this helps you to solve the problem